# Let $K$ be a local field and $K'$ be it's finite extension. Then, why ${K'}^{nr}/K^{nr}$ is finite extension?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, class-field-theory, local-field, unramified-extension

Let $K$ be a local field and $K'$ be it's finite extension.
Then, why ${K'}^{nr}/K^{nr}$ is finite extension ?

Unramified extension of local field corresponds to extension of residue field.
So, I can translate this into the problem of finite field.
Let $k$ be a finite field, and $k'$ be it's finite extension.
Then, why algebraic closure of $k'$ is finite extension of $k$ ?

This is related to the Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', $p202$, $Cor7.3$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't follow your translation to a problem of finite fields, i.e. I do not understand why that statement about the finite fields $k, k'$ (which is trivially true, as any algebraic closure of $k'$ is an algebraic closure of $k$ as well) would imply the statement in question.

Comment: I for my part would take a set of generators of the field extension $K' \vert K$ and check if it also generates the extension $K'^{nr} \vert K^{nr}$.

Comment: I got it, let $K'＝K(α)$, then, $K'$ is union of K(α)({p^n-1 th root of unity}＝K([p^n-2 th root of unity})(α), so the result follows.